# Trait and Open-Closed principle

Tags: design-patterns

As wikipedia say about Open-Closed principle : In object-oriented programming, the open/closed principle states "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification" .

Does not Trait breaks Open-closed principle ?

Comment: Why do you think that traits break the OCP?

Comment: isn't that modification ?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean. There isn't enough information here to follow your thought process. You may edit the question to add some code showing a trait that violates OCP.

Comment: Simply you have a class and you add a trait to that class for more functionality , i think this breaks being closed for modification part of OCP

Comment: Sometimes adding a trait is fine.  Sometimes it indicates that the original class was not sufficiently 'open for extension'.  Sometimes it indicates that you don't understand how the original class is supposed to be extended.

Comment: What do you mean by trait ? A scala trait?

Comment: Scala or other languages which support traits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refers to traits like in PHP, i believe not, it would be the same as say that extends a class would break this principle. What this principle really say is that we should design our classes in a way that allow changes and addition ofs new behaviours without changing it's implementations. ex:

```
class Warrior
{

    private $weapon;

    public function pickWeapon(Weapon $weapon)
    {
        $this->weapon = $weapon;
    }

    public function attack()
    {
        echo "Attacking with a ".$this->weapon->name;
    }

}

abstract class Weapon
{

    public $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}

class Sword extends Weapon
{

}

class Axl extends Weapon
{

}

$sword = new Sword('word');
$warrior = new Warrior();
$warrior->pickWeapon($sword);
$warrior->attack();
```

This way my warrior can pick any weapon that is a subclass of Weapon Class, i could change the implementation in sword or add new types of weapons without modifying the warrior class. Sorry for the silly example lol

I hope I've helped.